# what is the double dot operator(..) in the python?

Tags: python-2.7, module

Before installing the package, I read the code and I got a question.

There is double dot in the code when the code calls a module, the module is tools.

What is the double dot in python?
The code wrote `from ..tools import *`.

You can find it here, https://github.com/synergetics/spectrum/blob/master/src/conventional/cum2x.py

The code is computing the bispectrum.

And do you know the other code analysing a wave interaction for python such as HOSA in MATLAB?

Answer (score 6):

In python, The . is just accessing an attribute. The attribute could be a class, an instance, a method/function, etc and The .. is just specify an relative address in Linux environment. It means go to ../tools folder and import everything inside it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
You said me that the double dot is just and relative address in Linux.
Then does the code including the double dot NOT work in Windows environment?

Comment: Your welcome. It works in windows as same as in Linux too. In python, double dot used for relative addressing. That's all.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail :)

Comment: This is wrong.  Read up on "relative imports" and you'll see that ".." is nothing special.  It has *nothing* to do with Linux filesystems and paths.